# Database search only returning 1 search result

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, search, android-studio

I have made a film database app where a user can search for a film, which then displays the search results in a scrollView. However whenever I search for a string that should bring back multiple films like "the", it will only return the first result it sees. Any idea why?

MainActivity:

```
public void search(View v){
    EditText search = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtSearch);
    String searchresult = "%" + search.getText().toString() + "%";
    db = new DbHelper(this).getReadableDatabase();
    String[] column = {"*"};
    String where = "film LIKE ? OR actor LIKE ? OR actor2 LIKE ? OR director LIKE ?";
    String[] selArgs = {searchresult, searchresult, searchresult, searchresult};
    Cursor results = db.query("FILMTABLE", column, where, selArgs, null, null, null);
    film(results);
}

public void film (Cursor c) {

        c.moveToFirst();
        int filmint = c.getColumnIndex("film");
        int id = c.getColumnIndex("id");
        String film = c.getString(filmint);
        int filmID = c.getInt(id);

        TextView txt = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        txt.setId(filmID);
        txt.setText(film);
        txt.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        txt.setTextSize(16);
        txt.setClickable(true);
        txt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity4.class);
                intent.putExtra(FILM_ID_KEY, String.valueOf(v.getId()));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
        scrollView.addView(txt);

    }
```

Comment: you are getting only one data...because you are taking only one data from the cursor. you need to loop through it with cursor.moveToNext() to get the remaining cursor dat if it has any. do remember to close the cursor finally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to iterate over the results using cursor.

```
if (c.moveToFirst())
    {
        do {
            // Get values here
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
c.close();
```

Comment: Perfect, can't believe I didn't see this. Thanks!